# Laravel Conditional query on relationships sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im trying to build a query to fetch all `Orders` that has relational `products`, where the `products` amount is greater or equal to a value.

An `order` can have many `products`, and products have a property named `amount`.
Now what I need to do is fetch `Orders`, where the total amount of `products` (sum of property amount, on all related `products`) meets the criteria.

```
$orders = Order::
when( $request->amount, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->whereHas('products', function($q) use ($request){
        $q->where('amount', '>=', $request->amount);
    });
})
->get();
```

This code works as far as to check the that the amount for every connected product is greater or equal to the input, but I can't wrap my head around getting it to check the `sum` of `amount` on all connected `products`. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```php
$orders = Order::
when( $request->amount, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->whereHas('products', function($q) use ($request){
        $q->select(DB::raw('sum(amount) amount'))
            ->having('amount', '>=', $request->amount);
    });
})
->get();
```